# Escape HTML using a whitelist

Tags: html, ruby, escaping, sanitization

There are some very comfortable whitelist [sanitizers](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) for Ruby, but I can't find a tool that does HTML escaping using a whitelist. All Ruby HTML escape libraries do only escape all HTML tags in a provided text. Is there a library that let me choose which tags to escape?

Comment: Is Sanitize the only one you've tried? Your question sounds like you've tried at least two, but you only point to one, leaving us guessing what else it might be you've tried. [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) is another one that might appeal to you.

Comment: Ok, it seems like loofah does support escaping, but I don't see a way to configure a whitelist.

Comment: Send a note to the developer. He was quite responsive when I was working with Loofah a couple years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The Sanitize library you linked to supports custom configurations. See the "Custom Configuration" heading in [the readme](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/blob/master/README.rdoc). The "elements" option sounds just like what you're looking for — you can specify an array of tags to allow.

```
  :elements => %w[
    a abbr b blockquote br cite code dd dfn dl dt em i kbd li mark ol p pre
    q s samp small strike strong sub sup time u ul var
  ]
```

Comment: I don't see that the Sanitize library supports HTML escaping out of the box. With just specifying this "elements" option it would just strip those tags out (and not escaping it). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "escaping" tags?